# Two quick create forms are opened from Subgrid on "New" button click

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have kind of unusual issue with one of my subgrids in CRM.

On the Main form for an entity i have several subgrids, each of them for records from different entity.

When creating new record from subgrid, all of the forms are opened as expected, except one. It opens two quick create forms.

Forms are not opened normally, one following another. First one looks fine, except there is display name displayed twice. Another form doesn't display any field, just the close button. You can see the issue in the attached images.

I have checked Command for "New" Subgrid button in Ribbon Workbench, and there is nothing more than standard command. I have also tried to do this in several browsers, but the issue continued to appear. I have checked JavaScript functions and none of them is connected with this form.

Now I have lack of ideas what could cause this issue.

I need help for this if anyone had similar issue.

[image: first form]

[image: second form]

Comment: Just brainstorming, did you try removing that sub grid and adding again?

Comment: in the meantime error appeared and disappeared randomly. I gave a try to your idea and it solved the problem. It was probably just some kind of bug